# inequality from eigenvalues and positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a positive definite matrix $V(x)=x^TBx>0$ for any vector $x≠0$. we have $λ_{min}||x||^2≤V(x)≤λ_{max}||x||^2$ for any $x≠0$ , Then we could derive a upperbound
$$||x||\leq\ \bigg(\frac{V(x)}{\lambda_{min}}\bigg)^{\large\frac{1}{2}}$$

My question is: isn't the form $x^TBx=\lambda ||x||^2$ only works for the eigenvectors? Which means there are some eigenvalues $\lambda$ associate with. What if the $x$ is not the eigenvector, is above upperbound still hold for all $x$ satisfy $x^TBx>0$?

Comment: If euclidian, $x^T B x$ always gives you a number, but that does not mean the number is equal to $\lambda ||x||^2$. At least this is how I am intuitively visualizing the problem, and the expression $\lambda_{min} ||x||^2 \leq V(x) \leq \lambda_{max} ||x||^2$ does not restrict to the "equal to $\lambda ||x||^2$" case.

Comment: By the spectral theorem, there is an orthonormal (unitary) basis consisting of eigenvectors of $B$. Write $x$ as a linear combination of these basis vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric, then $\mathbb{R}^n$ has an orthonormal basis $\{q_1, \dots, q_n\}$ of eigenvectors of $B$. Thus if $\{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n\}$ are the corresponding eigenvalues and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then
$$x = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x, q_j)q_j,$$
$$Bx = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x, q_j)\lambda_jq_j,$$
$$V(x) = (Bx, x) = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x, q_j)^2\lambda_j.$$
The bounds on $V(x)$ follow immediately.

If $B$ is not symmetric, then set $S = \frac{1}{2}(B + B^T)$, the symmetric part of $B$. Since $B - S = \frac{1}{2}(B - B^T)$ is antisymmetric, $((B - S)x, x) = -(x, (B - S)x) = -((B - S)x, x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Thus $((B - S)x, x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Thus $(Bx, x) = (Sx, x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now the bounds for $V(x)$ in the symmetric case apply, though with eigenvalues of $S$ instead of $B$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I could understand this equation $x = \sum_{j = 1}^{n}(x_i, q_j)q_j$, but cannot follow since the second one. Would you please elaborate abit

Comment: all good now, cheers